# Problem with iteration on a string in batchfile FOR Loop

Tags: string, for-loop, batch-file, substring

I have a batch file that takes some files in different folders.
I want then to analyze the path of those files, and for that I am using an iteration of string.

Here is the problematic part of my code:

```
REM Put the string of the folder path in "variable_name"
SET variable_name=a
REM Iterate on the string
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=\" %%a IN ("!variable_name!") DO (
     REM I check the result of the iteration
     ECHO %%a
)
```

For a classic Path folder such as C:\Users\Me\XXX

I would like the return:

```
C:
Users
Me
XXX
```

But I got the return:

```
C:
```

Comment: Your question is unclear and doesn't show any effort on your part to solve it yourself.

Comment: Slightly different: For each string iterate through all substrings with length 1,then length 2,... For each substring check if it is contained in one of the other strings. If not you have found the (or one of) shortest possible identifying part. Continue at beginning with next string.

Comment: "Mat" is not even unique, is it? I mean, that is a proper substring of "Matt" as well as the full string "Mat".

Comment: Sayse: Could you please explain how a proposal of algorithm is "not any effort to solve it?"
Michael Butscher: Thank you for your proposal, I think it save some iterations. You can give it as an answer?
JohanL: you're right, I did not notice that. This is a particular case that I don't think I will meet in the "true world"